# SAS Compare values across multiple variables

Tags: arrays, sas, multiple-columns

I have the following example data set with an ID and the contract status in six months (01/2017 - 06/2017).

Example data:

```
ID   Month1   Month2   Month3   Month4   Month5   Month6**
12   5        5        5        5        5        5
34   5        5        6        6        5        5
56   6        6        6        -7       -7       -7
78   6        6        5        5        5        5
12   5        5        5        5        6        -7
```

If the status is 5 the ID is active, if 6 it's canceled and -7 is "not able to reactivate".

I want to check two kind of changes: 
1) IDs which change from status 5 to 6
2) IDs which change from 6 to 5

When the status changes from 5 to 6 I want a new variable "churn" containing the month in which the status changes to 6. 
For the second group, I want a new variable "reactivation" containing the month in which the status changes to 5.
If an ID is in both groups (from 5 to 6 to 5) both variables should be filled.

What I have so far is an array, which shows me how many status matches occur in one row, but I do not get the next step. Here is the code:

```
data want (drop= i j);
    set have (obs=100);
    array stat_check {*} month1-month6;
    sum=0;
    do i=1 to dim(stat_check)-1;
        do j=i+1 to dim(stat_check);
            sum=sum(sum,stat_check(i) eq stat_check(j));
        end;
    end;
run;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your data as text not an image, otherwise you're asking people to both type out your data and solve your problem.

Comment: You'll need to declare an array for your 6 columns and when the condition is met, use the `vname` function to get the right variable name. I'll be glad to help you further if you're stuck, but only if you go the extra mile, as Reeza suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, it's my first post here and just used the screenshot tool. I added the data lines as text and the code I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

For an array approach, sounds like you need to compare each variable in the array to the variable immediately before it. You don't need two passes through the array, only one. You want to compare month2 to month1, month3 to month2 ... month6 to month5.

I would try something like (untested):

```
data want (drop= month);
    set have (obs=100);
    array stat_check {*} month1-month6;
    sum=0;
    do month=2 to dim(stat_check);
        if stat_check{month}-stat_check{month-1} = 1 then Churn=month;
        else if stat_check{month}-stat_check{month-1} = -1 then Reactivation =month;
    end;
run;
```

If you could have multiple churns or multiple reactivations for the same ID, that would capture the latest churn or reactivation.

But honestly, I would transpose the data to have one row per ID-month. That would avoid the need for an array, and would allow you to capture multiple churns/reactivations. Generally it is easier to work with tall skinny data rather than short wide data. For example, it would be easy to count the number of months each ID was active.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. vname function is  used to get the variable name (month)

```
data two (drop= i j);
set one;
array stat_check {*} m1-m6;
sum=0;
do i=1 to dim(stat_check)-1;
    do j=i+1 to dim(stat_check);
        sum=stat_check(i)-stat_check(j);
        if sum=1 then churn=vname(stat_check(i)); 
        if sum=-1 then reactivation=vname(stat_check(i));
    end;
end;
```

run;